# "Could not find file" where file definitively, absolutely, exists with total and complete certainty

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-project

I am creating a setup project in visual studio, I included a file into the project NuVisions.sqlite to be installed. When attempting to build I get the following error:

```
Error   3   Could not find file 'Z:\work\neothinktank.net\newlee\NuVisions\NuDAO\NuVisions.sqlite' 'The parameter is incorrect.'    Z:\work\neothinktank.net\newlee\NuVisions\SetupBionetics\SetupBionetics.vdproj  SetupBionetics
```

The only problem is that I am absolutely 1000% certain with no doubt of any kind whatsoever that the file in question does exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out why this happens after so long.

Z: is a network drive and apparently VS gets a bit cranky when storing projects on network drives in certain instances.

Comment: Thanks for coming back after so many months to answer your own question. Saved my hair :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an annoying bug in Windows that pops up occasionally when handling large projects with long paths. The issue is you can only pass 32K characters on a commandline or to exec(). Anything past that gets silently truncated causing claims of missing files and bad parameters. It can happen when compile scripts are passing lots of files to a linker.

I realise it's a long-shot but any chance that might be the case?

Comment: Tried moving everything to a shorter path but it seems to be giving the same error. I've also migrated to VS2010 in the mean time for unrelated reasons but it STILL seems to be giving me the same error.